# MySql: count(*) from two selects

Tags: mysql, sql, select, count

I have 2 tables:

```
t_job
 - id
 - name

t_person:
 - id
 - name
 - job_id (fk t_job->id)

t_other_jobs
 - person_id (fk t_person->id)
 - job_id (fk t_job->id)
```

So basically I have people who have main job and 0 or more secondary jobs.
What I want to do is create query that gives me something like this:

```
PERSON NAME | ALL JOBS COUNT
```

and

```
JOB NAME | HOW MANY PEOPLE HAVE THEM
```

So if a person have main job (its a foreign key so he must have it) and 2 other jobs. Result would be:

```
Jorge | 3
```

Comment: You can remove the column `job_id` from the `t_person` and have a new column in the `t_other_jobs` as a flag to determine which one of them is the main one; `IsMain` as boolean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

1st Query (`PERSON NAME | ALL JOBS COUNT`)

```
SELECT name PersonName, maincount + Count(o.Job_Id) AS AllJobsCount
FROM (
  SELECT p.Id, p.name, COUNT(m.Id) AS MainCount
  FROM  t_person p
  LEFT JOIN t_job m ON  p.job_id = m.Id
  GROUP BY P.Id
) a
Left Join t_other_jobs o ON A.Id = o.person_id
GROUP BY a.Id
```

2nd Query (`JOB NAME | HOW MANY PEOPLE HAVE THEM`)

```
SELECT j.Name JobName, 
       (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM t_person WHERE job_id=j.Id) +
       (SELECT COUNT(1) FROM t_other_jobs WHERE job_id=j.Id) AS Count
FROM t_job j
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you stated they will always have a job, you can just count their other jobs and add 1:

```
SELECT
  p.id,
  p.name,
  count(o.job_id)+1 as Jobs
FROM
  t_person p
LEFT JOIN 
  t_other_jobs o
ON
  p.id=o.person_id
GROUP BY
  p.id, p.name;
```

Comment: I just figured out I misstyped the query I wanted from it ;) What I wanted is more like (JOB NAME | HOW MANY PEOPLE HAVE THEM) including possibility to have the same jobs in one person (example: Jon have jobs: A, A, B, D -> count: 4 )

Comment: @gemGreg: Please consider asking that as a new question then, as several people have already invested their time suggesting solutions to your original question (which may still be useful to someone, by the way).

Comment: I added 2nd query. Was thinking of adding new question but it seems all answers are here nicely answered ;) Thanks for help everyone. You are briliant

Answer (score 0):

This qwery will give you your first result.

```
select 
    person.id,
    count(distinct (person.job_id)) + count(other_jobs.job_id) as All_job
from
    person
        Inner JOin
    other_jobs
where
    person.id = other_job.person_id
group by person.id
```

This will give you the second one.

```
select 
    job.name, count(distinct (person.id)) as no_of_people
from
    person
        INNER JOIN
    job ON person.job_id = job.id
group by job_id 
UNION select 
    job.name, count(distinct (person_id)) as no_of_people
from
    other_job
        INNER join
    job ON job.id = other_job.job_id
group by job_id;
```